# Probability questions of watch problem

Tags: probability

> Factory A produces 1 bad watch in 100 and factory B produces 1 bad watch in 200. You are given two watches from one of the factories (chosen with equal probability) and you don't know which one.
>
> 1. What is the probability that the second watch works?
> 2. Given that the first watch works, what is the probability that the second watch works?

According to me, the answer should be $\frac{397}{800}$ for both.

Comment: Which part is your answer for?  If you want confirmation, you should explain how you got it.  It is much easier to check answers than to generate them.  What is your question?

Comment: I found both same answer

Comment: I took M be the event for that both watches chosen from same factory  ,  then P (M)= 1/4 ,  Again if we consider  H1 and H2 are events that  1st or 2nd watch be bad . Then P (H2` int. M)= 1/4 (99/100 +199/200)= 397/800 .  And for  2nd case since the events H1 and H2 are Independent  Thus H2` remains same.

Comment: It sounds to me like the two are guaranteed to come from the same factory

Comment: Yes, that is a confusion, because nothing  such mentioned  , that problem comes on yesterday's isi m.math entrance.

Comment: What is ISI? I've been seeing this a few times over the past few days, but no idea what it refers to.

Comment: Indian statistical institute

Comment: I read "two watches from one of the factories" to mean the watches come from the same factory.  Presumably the factory is chosen at random with probability $\frac 12$ each, but the question should say that.  For the second part, the fact that the first lot works makes it more likely they both came from B.

Answer (score 3):

For part 1, since the watches are independently picked:
$$P=\frac12\cdot\frac{99}{100}+\frac12\cdot\frac{199}{200}=\frac{397}{400}$$
which is not $\frac{397}{800}$.

For part 2, use the law of total probability. The probability that both watches work is
$$\frac12\cdot\frac{99^2}{100^2}+\frac12\cdot\frac{199^2}{200^2}=\frac{78805}{80000}$$
The probability of the first watch working is the same as the answer to part 1. Therefore
$$P=\frac{78805/80000}{397/400}=\frac{15761}{15880}$$

Comment: (Chosen with equal probably )is not given on question .someone edited it here. So I can't agree about 1/2 , I think  it will be1/4. @part 1 .

Comment: @S.A If I hadn't edited that in, how could I answer the question?

Comment: Hummmm u r right.