# Probability about functioning of two watches

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If factory A produces $1$ faulty watch in $100$ watches and factory B produces $1$ faulty watch in $200$. You are given two watches, you know that one is form factory A and one is form factory B. You don't know which is from which factory. Then

a) What is the probability that the second watch works?

b) If the first watch works, then what is the probability that the second one will be working?

My approach:

a) Say $A_1$ and $A_2$ be the events that the an watch is form factory A or factory B respectively. Let $W$ denotes the event that the second watch is working. Of course $ P(A_1)=P(A_2)=0.5$.

Then $P(W)= P(W/A_1)P(A_1)+P(W/A_2)P(A_2) = \frac{99}{100}(0.5)+\frac{199}{200}(0.5) =0.9925$

b) Say $W_1$ and $W_2$ be two events such that  first and second watches are working respectively. So $W_1 \cap W_2$ denotes both the watches are working. Then $P(W_1 \cap W_2$)= $(\frac{99}{100})(\frac{199}{200})$.

Hence $P({W_2}/{W_1})= \frac{P(W_1 \cap W_2)}{P(W_1)}$= $\frac{(\frac{99}{100})(\frac{199}{200})}{0.9925} \approx 0.992494$.

Am I correct?

Comment: This is not clear.  What do you mean by "the second watch"?  What process are you using to sample the watches?

Comment: sorry, I missed a line. Let me edit this one please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Probability questions of watch problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2281527/probability-questions-of-watch-problem)

Comment: Please you see that this question is slightly different... @ParclyTaxel

Comment: The thing to keep in mind is that knowing that $W_1$ is working is evidence that it comes from $B$, since $B$ is more likely to produce a working watch.  Assuming your prior is that it had a $\frac 12$ chance of coming from $B$ you need to use Bayes' Theorem to re-estimate that probability.

Comment: It doesn´t play a role if the first watch works. Just focus on the second watch. What is the probability that the second watch works?

Comment: @callculus  I disagree.  Knowing that the first watch works suggests that it is the one that comes from the better factory.  It's critical that one comes from $A$ and the other from $B$, so this conclusion hurts the second watch's chances.

Comment: For intuition, take an extreme version.  Say that $99.999\%$ of the watches from $A$ are defective while only $.00001\%$ of those from $B$ are.  Then knowing that $W_1$ worked would be virtual proof that it came from $B$, so you'd be nearly certain that the second watch was defective.

Comment: Yes , I agree with @lulu, but I didn't get how to use Bayes theorem here...

Comment: @ArnabChowdhury: Please point out the differences; I can't spot them.

Comment: @lulu I think my comment was right. But after reading the answer of the OP I noticed that she/he has calculated this way. So I agree to the OP's solution for a).

Comment: @callculus  Oh, the answer for a) is correct.  But for $b)$ we assume that we have checked $W_1$ and seen that is working, which provides (quite weak) evidence that it comes from $B$...the better factory.  As I pointed out above, this effect is almost insignificant with these numbers but is quite strong if the failure rates of the two factories are far apart.

Comment: In the other question, it was given that both the watches come from the same factory... @joriki

Answer (score 1):

As there is some disagreement in the comments, I'll post some notes.

To make the problem more general, suppose that a watch from factory $A$ (resp $B$) is working with probability $P_A$ (resp. $p_B$).

At the start we have no idea which watch comes from which factory, so our prior must be to assign equal probability (i.e. $\frac 12$) probability to each.

Thus the probability that the second one is working is $$\frac 12\times p_A+\frac 12 \times p_B=\frac {p_A+p_B}2$$

Note:  this is entirely consistent with the argument given by the OP.

Now assume that we have seen that $W_1$ is working.  That is (weak) evidence for the claim that $W_1$ comes from $B$ since $B$ is more likely to make working watches.  We need to use Bayes to re-estimate the probability that $W_1$ comes from $A$ or $B$.

As we saw in the first computation, the total probability that it is defective is $\frac 12\times (p_A+p_B)$.  Of that, the probability that it comes from $A$ explains $\frac 12\times p_A$.  Thus the re-estimated probability that it comes from $A$ is $$P_1(A)=\frac {p_A}{p_A+p_B}$$

Similarly $$P_1(B)=\frac {p_B}{p_A+p_B}$$

Note as a sanity check that if $p_A=p_B$ then we just get $\frac 12$ again as nothing has happened to break the symmetry.

Of course $P_2(A)=P_1(B), P_2(B)=P_1(A)$.

Now we can use the revised probabilities to conclude that, given that $W_1$ is working, the probability that the second is working is $$\frac {p_B}{p_A+p_B}\times p_A+\frac {p_A}{p_A+p_B}\times p_B=\frac {2p_Ap_B}{p_A+p_B}$$

Using your numbers we get $\boxed {0.992493703}$ which is slightly less than the $.9925$ for part $A$, reflective of the fact that the evidence that $W_1$ came from $B$ was quite weak.

As a (crude) sanity check, note that taking $p_A=p_B=\psi$ makes the answer $\psi$, as it should.

Comment: Thats exactly  how I proceed

Comment: That may well be, I had trouble following your argument.  That's why I wrote it out in detail.

Comment: Actually I should have written the intermediate steps, I apologise for that...

Comment: No apologies needed.  I had the sense (possibly incorrect) that there was some confusion in the comments, so I thought I'd just write it all out in detail.  Maybe too much detail!